# Should I use the "drop_first"-parameter of pd.get_dummies() when NaN does exists?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Python and ML, so my question might be easy!
I would like to know if I have to use "drop_first"-parameter of the pandas.get_dummies-function when I have NaN in the column.

Please see below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 'Test', 3],
                        [0, None, 1],
                        [2, 'Bla', 4],
                        [9, 'Foo', 2]], 
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3], 
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
print(df.head())
```

This will result in this output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1  Test     3
1     0   NaN     1
2     2   Bla     4
3     9   Foo     2
```

All right that's fine. 
Now the get_dummies from pandas (imported as pd):

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df['Col2'])
print(new_df)
```

And the result is:

```
   Bla  Foo  Test
0    0    0     1
1    0    0     0
2    1    0     0
3    0    1     0
```

All right! My NaN is translated into `[0, 0, 0]`. I think that's all right for further algorithms.

Here is what I'm wondering about. When executing the following:

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df['Col2'], drop_first=True)
print(new_df)
```

The result is:

```
   Foo  Test
0    0     1
1    0     0
2    0     0
3    1     0
```

First column was dropped, that's fine. But now I have two rows with `[0, 0]` and it's not possible to trace the value back to the original value. Both rows would be translated into the category "Bla" now. Correct?

What I ask myself is, should I use the "drop_first"-parameter when I have NaN in the column?

Thanks,

Hannes

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the data. What do you want to do with the `new_df`? You could also drop the nan-values first with `df.dropna()` and then use `get_dummies()`

Comment: thanks for your help @onno

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is correct. Dropping the first raw will have that impact. So there are some solutions that are related with dealing with missing values:

1. as suggested by @onno you can drop the NaN rows;
2. You keep your first approach and [0,0,0] means unknown/NaN;
3. You try to estimate the NaN values based on the other columns;

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I thought about something like this to handle the problem in general `new_df = pd.get_dummies(df['Col2'], drop_first=df['Col2'].isnull().values.all())`

I will check the estimation of NaN next.